# Bind route parameter to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Lets say i have a route like the following

```
/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Is it possible to bind the id to a property in my model

```
public ActionResult Update(Model model)
{
    model.Details.Id <-- Should contain the value from the route...
}
```

Where my model class is the following?

```
public class Model
{  
    public Details Details {get;set;}
}

public class Details
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create your own custom model binder.

```
public class SomeModelBinder : IModelBinder {

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("id");

        SomeModel model = new SomeModel() { Details = new Details() };
        model.Details.Id = int.Parse(value.AttemptedValue);

        //Or you can load the information from the database based on the Id, whatever you want.

        return model;
    }

}
```

To register your binder you add this to your `Application_Start()`

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SomeModel), new SomeModelBinder());
```

Your controller then looks exactly as you have it above. This is a very simplistic example but the easiest way to do it. I'll be happy to provide any additional help.